# construct janusgraph a get query in python

Tags: python, gremlin, janusgraph

Is it possible to construct a query in parts and run  in gremlin python.
some thing like this -

```
q="hasLabel('foo')"
m="has('type','goo')"
g.V().q.m.values('ABC').toList()
```

instead of directly running

```
g.V().hasLabel('foo').has('type','goo').values('ABC').toList()
```

I tried this and i am getting - [] 
whereas it is producing results for

```
g.V().hasLabel('foo').has('type','goo').values('ABC').toList()
```

Is there any way to construct such a query?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
t = g.V()
t = t.hasLabel('foo')
t = t.has('type','goo')
t.values('ABC').toList()
```

which would allow you to pass around `t` (i.e. the `Traversal`object) to different functions that would each add to it. I suppose that child traversals could be constructed somewhat in the manner you're describing:

```
child = __.outE().count()
g.V().group().by(child).toList()
```